# Evaluate the integral $\int e^{-it} \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals, convolution

I need to find the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x dt \, e^{-it}\text{sinc}(t)
$$
where
$$
    \text{sinc}(t) = \frac{\text{sin}(t)}{t}.
$$
I need it to perform a convolution of the function $e^{-ix}\text{sinc}(x)$ with a rectangular window. WolframAlpha tells me that the antiderivative is
$$
    \frac{1}{2}i\big(-\log(x) + \text{Ei}(-2ix)\big).
$$
I would like to know how to arrive at this result myself, I can see which terms in the integral turn into which terms of the solution, but I can't seem to get from the integral I have to the solution WolframAlpha provides me. I get stuck with infinities or the likes.

Could someone provide me with a derivation of this, or give me some hints as for what I need to do to obtain this result?

Comment: I think you mean $dx$ in the first integral.

Comment: @Zima oh, of course. I fixed it.

Comment: Try replacing $sinx$ by the identity: $sinx=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: @Fotis thats what I've tried so far, I can get a $1/x$ term and a $e^{-2ix}/2ix$ term, but I cant seem to properly transition to the definition of $\text{Ei}(x)$ and the logarithm

Comment: @NielsSlotboom do you want the integral to be indefinent or is okay if it's of the form $\int_{x}^{\infty}$

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you're lost. If you're integrating $1/x$ and $e^{-2ix}/x$ then the result easily follows by the definiton of $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ and the logarithm.

Comment: @Accelerator I have uploaded an image of my steps so far [here](https://i.imgur.com/1j9h6lO.png). The difficulties I am facing are with the $-\infty$ boundary for the $1/x$ integral and I forgot too much about complex line integration to go from an integral on the real axis (as in the definition of $\text{Ei}(x)$) to one that contains complex boundaries.

Comment: @Fotis Preferrably $\int_{-\infty}^x$, but I think I should be able to do what I have to do with any sort of integration bounds where one is a variable and the other is constant.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were calculating the indefinite integral. I didn't know you were concerned with the bounds. You might want to add that into the original post just in case people get confused.

Comment: @Accelerator will do. It doesn't matter much if its a definite integral or not, I need to find the convolution of the integrand with a rectangular window so I am only concerned with the boundary values anyways, the integration constant (and by that the constant bound) is not too important

Comment: Can you specify what $x$ is? I've tried multiple values of $x$ and your integral doesn't seem to converge.

Comment: $x$ should be a free variable, and according to the solution wolframalpha gives there should be no convergence issues, the function itself is very well-behaved (basically a sinc with an additional phase)
But convergence problems is something that I've faced in my attempts as well, possibly my lower bound of $-\infty$ is problematic. However, the lower bound does not matter much, as I need the integral $\int_a^b$ in the end. The reason I provided the antiderivative in the question is because wolframalpha doesnt like it when I put integral boundaries, but seems to accept indefinite integrals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145778/discussion-between-accelerator-and-niels-slotboom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the antiderivative in terms of $\sin$ and writing that function in its complex exponential form gives
\begin{multline*}
\int \frac{e^{-iz}}{z} \sin z \,dz = \int \frac{1}{t} e^{-iz} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{iz} - e^{-iz}\right)\,dz = \frac{1}{2i}\int\frac{1}{z}(1 - e^{-2 i z})\,dz \\= -\frac{i}{2} \left[\int \frac{dz}{z} - \int \frac{e^{-2 i z}}{z} \,dt\right] = -\frac{i}{2} \left( \log z + \operatorname{Ei}_1(2iz)\right) + C\end{multline*}

For any $C$, this function has a removable singularity at $z = 0$, with limit $C + \frac{3\pi}{4} + i \cdot \frac{1}{2} (\log 2 + \gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. So, the function is an antiderivative everywhere except along the branch cut of $\log$ (we choose the branch cut so that $\arg z \in [-\pi, \pi)$). If we define $F(z)$ to be the antiderivative with $C = -\left[\frac{3\pi}{4} + i \cdot \frac{1}{2} (\log 2 + \gamma)\right]$, so that the limit of $F(0)$ as $t \to 0$ along the real axis, then the restriction $F\vert_\Bbb R$ satisfies $F\vert_\Bbb R(-t) = -\overline{F\vert_\Bbb R(t)}$.

For real $t$, $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \operatorname{Ei}_1(2 i t) = \pm \pi i$, which is finite. So, since $\log t$ is unbounded as $t \to \pm \infty$, $\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^{-it}}{t} \sin t \,dt$ does not converge for any $x$. This essentially occurs because $e^{-it} \sin t$ has a nonzero constant component.

Here $\operatorname{Ei}_1(z)$ is the analytic continuation of $$z \mapsto \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-sz}}{s} \,ds$$
to $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$. This function is realized to the (complex-valued) one-argument exponential integral function, $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$, by
$$\operatorname{Ei}(z) = -\operatorname{Ei}_1(-z) + \frac{1}{2} \log z - \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{z}\right) - \log(-z).$$

Comment: What definition of $\text{Ei}(x)$ did you use? I was unsure if I could just replace $\int\frac{e^-{2it}}{t}dt$ with the exponential integral as the definition of the exponential integral contains boundaries.

Comment: @NielsSlotboom I've tweaked the notation to make it clearer how the exponential integral here, $\operatorname{Ei}_1(z)$, differs from that presumably used by WolframAlpha (now denoted $\operatorname{Ei}$ here), and I've indicated how the two functions are related. For $x < 0$, $\operatorname{Ei}(x) = -\operatorname{Ei}_1(-x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^s}{s} \,ds$, but the extension to nonreal arguments is a little delicate, as is often the case when branch cuts of the logarithm are involved.

Comment: I tried plotting the function, and it looks to me as if it should be $F(-t) = -\overline{F(t)}$. The imaginary part of F should be even, and the real part odd (up to a complex constant).
Thank you for including the definition!

Comment: Yes, you're right, and that identity holds just for real $t$, I think. I've adjusted my answer (replaced $\log |t|$ with $\log t$ and modified the rest correspondingly) to avoid the explicit issue with the discontinuity at $0$.